# How to interpret a small variance?

Tags: statistics, variance

I have a variance that is small, less than 1, and i am not quite sure how i should interpret this. This means that the standard deviation is larger than the variance, which i don't intuitively understand. For reference, my mean is approximate 0.93 and my variance is approximately 0.8733

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't much to understand. The relationship between standard deviation and variance isn't of any statistical significance. Standard deviation is the (quadratic) mean deviation, and variance is the square of that. That automatically implies that standard deviation necessarily is closer to $1$ than variance.

Comment: I think it is perfectly OK to have SD greater than Variance when Var is lesser than 1

Comment: Okay, so there is no special significance of such a variance? Thanks. :-)

Comment: You mean your standard deviation is $.93$ (I assume this cause $.93^2$ is close to $.8733$.) This just means roughly that your distribution has an width/uncertainty of around $\pm .93$ (this is a very rough interpretation). The fact that it's bigger or smaller than one has absolutely no significance. You could just use different units for what you're measuring and make the standard deviation be numerically whatever you want... the value of one is not a meaningful reference. The variance is just the square of the standard deviation. Nothing significant about whether it's bigger or smaller.